# Checkbox checking snag

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, checkbox, selenium-chromedriver

https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/workspace/TMP_8Mcy38_15422/Gator/irsa/19142/tbview.html

I cannot select the checkboxes on this page using selenium webdriver.

This is an excerpt from the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
import shutil

     driver_path = 'C:/Windows/chromedriver.exe'
     driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
     driver.get('https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/Gator/nph-scan?mission=irsa&submit=Select&projshort=ZTF')

     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='ztf_objects_dr18']").click()
     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Select']").click()

     driver.find_element_by_name('objstr').send_keys(str(177.18609)+' '+str(21.47316))

     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='10']").clear()
     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='10']").send_keys('2')

     # Generate Text File
     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Run Query']").click()

     # Click on Download Button
    import time
    #print('going to sleep')
    time.sleep(2)
    #print('woke up')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@tabindex='-1']").click()
```

Result on running this

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@tabindex='-1']"}
```

Comment: After clicking on **Run Query** button, are you sure there are search results?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `2s` wait time is not enough for the page to load. Try using Selenium's [Explicit Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) instead of `time.sleep`.

Change below line:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@tabindex='-1']").click()
```

TO:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@tabindex='-1']"))).click()
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**NOTE:** Your XPATH expression `//input[@tabindex='-1']` is locating lot of elements(see screenshot below). In such instance, selenium may click the first occurring element from the top of HTML DOM.

[image]